# Pre-caching in memmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I need to read almost 100 binary files in pairs(each file is nearly 2GB), so essentially need to read two 2GB binary file at a time.

Have tried reading in chunks method and memmap, memmap is faster but the main bottleneck is copying the data from virtual memory, (i.e. np.copy()).

Also, running the same program with memmap twice is much faster(probably due to caching), so was thinking if its possible to ask memmap to pre-cache the next files or something, to make the program much efficient,

Any suggestion to improve is appreciated.

Comment: If you often need to access the same files, I'd suggest saving the files in h5py format.

Comment: @orlp Its not practically possible due to the amount of data and no of files.

Comment: Surely if you asked memmap to pre-cache the next file you'd just move the slow bit to the pre-caching step. You'd do exactly the same amount of work in the end so it'd take the same time overall.

Comment: @DavidW Was thinking of running pre-cache parallelly...