# Slow numpy memmap and fromfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, signal-processing, cython

I have multiple binary (structured) file, each of 2GB, which I am currently reading using memmap and processing the same. I want to minimise the time required by this IO process.

I am implementing this as a Cython function, though the copying of memmap  array to numpy array is quite fast (~3 sec) when same files are processed twice, it takes large amount of time if new files are to be read (~71 sec), possibly because of cache memory, this is the same with numpy fromfile as well.

Are there any other methods of reading large binary files efficiently?

**Edit (More information added):**

First Run (after clearing cache by echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches):

Time required to copy memap array as numpy array..71.1619570255 sec

Second Run (on same set of 2GB file, without clearing cache):

Time required to copy memap array as numpy array..2.86509585381 sec

Code used:

```
cpdef tuple decrypt_file(file_name, file_name1):

    cdef long long int templen = 0
    cdef long long int templen1= 0
    cdef np.ndarray tempcomf   =   np.zeros((templen, 1024),dtype=np.int8)
    cdef np.ndarray tempcomf1  =   np.zeros((templen1, 1024),dtype=np.int8)



    dt       = np.dtype([('header', 'S8'), ('Source', 'S10'), ('header_rest', 'S10'), ('Packet', '>u4'), ('data', '>i1', 1024)])
    comf     = np.memmap(file_name,  dtype = dt, mode = 'c')
    comf1    = np.memmap(file_name1, dtype = dt, mode = 'c')

    templen =   comf['Packet'][-1]-comf['Packet'][0]
    templen1=   comf1['Packet'][-1]-comf1['Packet'][0]

    t_1      =   time.time()
    tempcomf =   comf['data']
    tempcomf1=   comf1['data']
    print('Time take for memarray copy...'+str(time.time()-t_1))
    tempcomf = tempcomf.ravel()
    tempcomf1= tempcomf1.ravel()


    tempcomf_X =   np.array(tempcomf[1::2], order = 'F')
    tempcomf_Y =   np.array(tempcomf[0::2], order = 'F')
    tempcomf1_X=   np.array(tempcomf1[1::2],order = 'F')
    tempcomf1_Y=   np.array(tempcomf1[0::2],order = 'F')

    return tempcomf_X, tempcomf_Y, tempcomf1_X, tempcomf1_Y
```

Comment: memmap should be really fast, it is not really getting any faster with other methods. The behavior you observe makes no sense to me. We need more information on what you are doing exactly. I dont think it has anything to do with caching. Even copying all the data, in case "copy on write" is enabled should be much faster than 70 sec. After all 2 GB is not that much.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I have added more information, in the new edit. I guess the structure of the question was ambiguous, earlier (apologies for that). Also, I meant copying the memmap array into volatile memory (as numpy array), which is consuming large time.

Comment: A very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64699049/5769463